# Will writing million times to a file, spoil my harddisk?

Tags: c, file, io, storage, disk

I have a IO intensive simulation program, that logs the simulation trace / data to a file at every iterations. As the simulation runs for more than millions of iterations or so and logs the data to a file in the disk (overwrite the file each time), I am curious to know if that would spoil the harddisk as most of storage disk has a upper limit to  write/erase cycles ( eg. flash disk allow up to 100,000 write/erase cycles). Will splitting the file in to multiple files be a better option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to recognize that a million write calls to a single file may only write to each block of the disk once, which doesn't cause any harm to magnetic disks or SSD devices.  If you overwrite the first block of the file one million times, you run a greater risk of wearing things out, but there are lots of mitigating factors.  First, if it is a single run of a program, the o/s is likely to keep the disk image in memory without writing to disk at all in the interim — unless, perhaps, you're using a journalled file system.  If it is a journalled file system, then the actual writing will be spread over lots of different blocks.

If you manage to write to the same block on a magnetic spinning hard disk a million times, you are still not at serious risk of wearing the disk out.

A Google search on 'hard disk write cycles' shows a lot of informative articles (more particularly, perhaps, about SSD), and the related searches may also help you out.

Comment: Don't forget that the disk itself may have a cache that will coalesce writes.

Answer (score 1):

On an SSD, there is a limited amount of writes (or erase cycles to be more accurate) to any particular block. It's probably more than 100K to 1 million to any given block, and SSD's use "wear loading" to avoid unnecessary "writes" to the same block every time. SSD's can only write zeros, so when you "reset" a bit to one, you have to erase the whole block. [One could put an inverter on the cell to make it the other way around, but you get one or t'other, so it doesn't help much].

Real hard disks are more of a mechanical device, so there isn't so much of a with how many times you write to the same place, it's more the head movements.

I wouldn't worry too much about it. Writing one file should be fine, it has little consequence whether you have one file or many.

Comment: SLC - 100k write cycles, MLC - 3k, TLC 1k, but SLC is rare and expensive, most consumer drives are MLC and TLC.